# Vue can I set process.env.NODE_ENV

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, axios

Concerning modes and environmental variables as documented here

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes

I was rather confused why I can't set the following variable to **mock** for example. As the document seems to say this will be the **mode** that you pass in!

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

I have create the following server-mock command string in my **package.json** as follows

```
"serve-mock": "vue-cli-service serve --mode mock"
```

But when I run

```
npm run server-mock
```

The **process.env.NODE_ENV** is still set to **development** and not to **mock**. Am I supposed to set this in the **.env.mock** file? I presumed that it would be set based on the mode that was passed in as **mock**?

Comment: Here's a possible solution: a module called [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vue CLI's `serve` command uses the `mode` option to load environment variables from mode-specific `.env` files. It also sets the `NODE_ENV` to one of the three standard modes (`test`, `development`, or `production`) only if not already set. However, if the specified mode is not standard (as is the case with `mock`), Vue CLI [defaults to `development`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/eaa2b7341f174260f6ebc2345bd8e838f85a2ea3/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js#L123).

So, you could set `NODE_ENV=mock` inside `.env.mock` to bypass the `NODE_ENV` setting mentioned above.

Alternatively, you could [set `NODE_ENV` on the NPM script's command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56449/17893) in *nix shells:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve-mock": "NODE_ENV=mock vue-cli-service serve"
  }
}
```

For a cross-platform solution (including Windows), you could install [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) (as recommended in comments), and edit your NPM script as follows:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve-mock": "cross-env NODE_ENV=mock vue-cli-service serve"
  }
}
```